# Is it possible to use swt on Java 7

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

We recently upgraded from Java 6(32-bit) to Java 7 (64-bit) and I am trying to compile of our plugin projects.
I get an error below -

```
 Undefined reference: void org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button.setText(String)
[WARNING] Rule 5: org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.enforcer.CheckSignatureRule failed with message:
Signature errors found. Verify them and ignore them with the proper annotation if needed.
```

Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Are you using a 64-bit build of SWT? (SWT includes native libraries.)